# How to avoid CLOSE_WAIT in TCP/ip socket

Tags: c, linux, timer, tcpserver

By using select function handling multiple client connection in RPI using c. If CLOSE_WAIT came code is not working.if it occurs I am trying to kill the socket but code is hanging. Without restart how to resolve this 
Please help in this.....

When CLOSE_WAIT will come how to avoid this.

I am thinking it will come if we didn't close the socket but how to close during network loss. Or else How to do read timeout on server side

Comment: "*If CLOSE_WAIT came code is not working*" - then you are doing something wrong. Please show your actual code. `CLOSE_WAIT` happens on the server side only when a client gracefully closes its end of the connection (ie sends a `FIN` packet) before the server closes its end. Once the server has closes its end, the connection transitions out of `CLOSE_WAIT`. A connection being in `CLOSE_WAIT` will not prevent the server from handling other connections. It sounds like your server is simply not closing its sockets properly, such as if it is not handling socket close/error notifications correctly.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-cc-handling-multiple-clients-on-server-without-multi-threading/amp/

Comment: So, you just copy/pasted that code as-and compiled it is? Because that code has bugs in it. For instance, it is not `close()`'ing accepted sockets if the `clients[]` array is full. And it is handling errors from `send()` and `read()` at all. But it is handling graceful disconnects, at least, and should be `close()`'ing sockets for disconnected clients. But it is not `close()`'ing sockets for lost clients.

Comment: Yes I am using this as it is but actual my project is based on the client input RPI want to switch from AP to client when switching between the network I am closing the socket setting that array to zero and if array size cross 10 I am closing all opened socket. But before this i am getting CLOSE_WAIT and code is hanging

Comment: i don't think you understand what `CLOSE_WAIT` actually is. The code shown can't hang if `CLOSE_WAIT` occurs. Something else is going on. Like maybe no new client connecting to your server. Use a timeout with `select()`. Also, `select()` isn't the best choice for error handling. `epoll()` is a better option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try with epoll()

Answer (score 0):

Call `shutdown(fd, 2)` before `close(fd)`, otherwise your socket will go into CLOSE_WAIT state to wait for the FIN handshake.  This can take quite a while. I believe it is four minutes on Solaris, for example.

If you have a newer unix, you can use SHUT_RDWR instead of 2.

Comment: Any backing information? From my understanding, `close()` includes everything `shutdown()` does, and more.